# Silverlight 4: How to access control created from codebehind

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to create a method to draw a Line(path) between two UserControls. I found a post by someone that gave me a general pointer on how to do this, I implemented the code succesfully and started adapting it to my needs.

I am having a problem with accessing the user control:

```
Button b2 = new Button();
var transform2 = b2.TransformToVisual(b2.Parent as UIElement);
```

Works as it should, but my buttons get created dynamicaly through a method so I can't access them as "b2".

I tried the following:

```
var transfrom3 = canvas1.Children[0].TransformToVisual(canvas1.Children[0].Parent as UIElement);
```

but accessing it like that gives me an error on .Parent.

If have also tried:

```
                var p1 = this.FindName(ps.ProcessID.ToString());
                var p2 = this.FindName(ps.PreID.ToString());

                ////get geo data from both controls
                var transform1 = p1.TransformToVisual(p1.Parent as UIElement);
                var transform2 = p2.TransformToVisual(p2.Parent as UIElement);
```

Can anyone tell me how i can access these UserControls?

Comment: What's the error on `Parent`?

Comment: 'System.Windows.UIElement' does not contain a definition for 'Parent' and no extension method 'Parent' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.UIElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Everything works when I use the first example, but i create the button controls based on database data, I could be needing 30 buttons for example.

Answer (score 0):

This line ought to work:-

```
var transfrom3 = canvas1.Children[0].TransformToVisual(canvas1.Children[0].Parent as FrameworkElement);
```

as you have discovered `UIElement` doesn't have `Parent`, its the `FrameworkElement` that adds the `Parent` property.

However it would be better to access the control via its name (I'll assume you are assigning a `Name` to the dynamically added controls).

This:-

```
var p1 = this.FindName(ps.ProcessID.ToString());
```

ought to work assuming `this` is `UserControl` and the FrameworkElement in question was given the matching name in **code**:-

```
canvas1.Children.Add(new Button() {Name = ps.ProcessID.ToString(), Content="Hello"});
```

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer Anthony! I'm gonna try this out asap!

Comment: Doing that still wont give me access to the .Parent and yes I am naming the Controls as I add them, btw the usercontrol that we are talking about here is a Stackpanel that has multiple items in it. What I want to do is draw a Line/Path between two objects, I have the code from it from another question someone asked, but for that to work i need to be able to access .Parent in that line.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I did not see that you changed UIElement to FrameworkElement, this setup works for me now:

```
                var control1 = this.FindName(ps.ProcessID.ToString()) as FrameworkElement;
                var control2 = this.FindName(ps.PreID.ToString()) as FrameworkElement;
                var transform1 = control1.TransformToVisual(control1.Parent as UIElement);
                var transform2 = control2.TransformToVisual(control2.Parent as UIElement);
```

If I add the control to a var as a FrameworkElement, then I can use the .Parent on the control again.

Thanks for your answer Anthony!